# How to solve rosmake failed 'c++: internal compiler error' of rgbdslam?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam).

I try to rosmake on ROS fuerte of rgbdslam

I run:

```
  svn co http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk/g2o
  sed 's/depend package="eigen"/rosdep name="eigen"/g' rgbdslam/manifest.xml > rgbdslam/manifest.xml.bak; mv rgbdslam/manifest.xml.bak rgbdslam/manifest.xml
  sed 's/find_package(Eigen)/find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)/g' rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt > rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt.bak; mv rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt.bak rgbdslam/CMakeLists.txt
```

When I rosmake, it shows:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['rgbdslam']                        
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']                                
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120825-152734
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
  ['rgbdslam']                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> g2o [ make ]                                           
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 lineso: 627.8 sec ]              [ 1 Active 12/32 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ 13%] Built target test_slam_interface
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 23%] Built target stuff
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 41%] Built target core
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 45%] Built target g2o_cli_library
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 47%] Built target g2o_cli_application
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 48%] Built target solver_cholmod
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 61%] Built target types_slam2d
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 63%] Built target math_groups
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 67%] Built target types_slam3d
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    [ 69%] Building CXX object g2o/apps/g2o_interactive/CMakeFiles/g2o_interactive_library.dir/graph_optimizer_sparse_online.cpp.o
    c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    make[3]: *** [g2o/apps/g2o_interactive/CMakeFiles/g2o_interactive_library.dir/graph_optimizer_sparse_online.cpp.o] Error 4
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[2]: *** [g2o/apps/g2o_interactive/CMakeFiles/g2o_interactive_library.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/slam/g2o/build/g2o/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package g2o written to: Active 12/32 Complete ]
  [ rosmake ]    /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120825-152734/g2o/build_output.log
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< g2o [FAIL] [ 627.72 seconds ]                          
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package g2o. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
  [ rosmake ] Built 13 packages with 1 failures.                                  
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120825-152734               
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$ gcc --version
  gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
  Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
  
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/slam/rgbdslam$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42301/how-to-solve-rosmake-failed-%27c++:-internal-compiler-error%27-of-rgbdslam?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

This is an error that I have seen in relation to the availability of lesser RAM or swap space. The discussion in the following link may help:
[GNU gcc Bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34882)

Further, I would recommend you to update your gcc to the latest version which could be a possible cause for this problem. You may check the version of your gcc using

> gcc --version

Currently it is 4.6.x

The above solutions are general ones that may sometimes solve the error that you have got.

I hope this helps you to get started to resolve your issue. Update your question after having tried the above methods if your error still does not disappear.

All the best,
Regards,

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-28**:
My gcc version is already 4.6.1, and I haven't tried to update gcc version. I have revised my original post. What to do next? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-29**:
As @SivamPillai said, try more RAM or a bigger swap partition.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-02**:
How to extend swap partition? Which size is enough? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-02**:
That's not a ros-related question. I think it's best if you google for it. You will find plenty of information on how to resize. I suggest to make it at leat 4gb big, depending on the ram you have.